# Mercurial - largefile xxxx not available from http://foo/blah/blah

Tags: mercurial, large-files

I cloned a large Mercurial repo, made some changes and then pushed it to a different server.

Some new developers are coming on to the project and are trying to clone the repo from the new server, using

> hg clone -r "branchname" http://ourserver/scm/hg/repo

which successfully downloads the source. But, largefiles are missing, so we try

> hg lfpull --rev "all()"

Which results in a whole lot of errors like this:

> Foo/Bar/afile.7z: largefile xxxx not available from http://ourserver/scm/hg/repo

If I go into the Mercurial web interface, browse to a file and download it via the "raw" link, I get a file with the correct filename, but it only contains what I am guessing is an ID. For instance, one PDF contains only:

> f91476a8c2cc0a164c0880d128ca80776a8a934e

Any suggestions? I have all of these files locally, but they came from the original server. How do I make sure that largefiles are pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just idea:

> When you push a changeset that affects largefiles to a remote
>   repository, its largefile revisions will be uploaded along with the
>   changeset. This ensures that the central store gets a copy of every
>   revision of every largefile. Note that the remote Mercurial must also
>   have the largefiles extension enabled for this to work.

It *seems*, that "different server" doesn't have LargeFiles enabled, thus - everybody will have a mess with files, which repo with LF-extension doesn't store in default repo storage (repo contain only "links" to revision of largefile in it's storage)

Comment: Hmmm... my admin swears that largefiles is enabled. I'll ping him again. Thanks.

Comment: How would I confirm that largefile support is enabled on the server?

Comment: @DavidLively : "Each local repository has a local largefiles store in '.hg/largefiles'." Central repo is also local repo... or just check `.hgrc`